# Need to implement signature capture

Tags: android

I've got a dispatch/delivery/tracking application running on (ugh) Windows mobile that allows a signature capture.

I *really* want to port this to Android to give my customers another option (thankfully) from Windows mobile devices.

Is it possible to capture a signature on the device?  What are my options here?

Thanks.

Comment: duplicate question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7228191/android-signature-capture , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4710797/android-signature-capture, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6834354/how-to-capture-human-signature ect....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am writing one based one of the sample apps in the Android SDK. Not done yet, but so far I have it capturing a simple drawing based on a Custom View. Here's the example:
[TouchPaint.java](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/TouchPaint.html)

Comment: I just figured out this example is for 2.3, which explains why it works on my AVD and not my N1 =(

Comment: This sample is also for 2.0 and 2.2, maybe even lower than this.

Comment: @RangerRich - i used the same example, but the signatures look sort of airbrushed and i'm trying to figure out how to make this example do solid lines.  that example works with api level 8 with a few edits.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a webv/javascript based signature tool. It can output in many formats and is modular so you only need to include the code to convert to one type (so it's fairly lightweight).

[jSignature](http://willowsystems.github.com/jSignature/#/about/)

Answer (score 0):

It's possible. One issue, however, is that very few Android devices have resistive touchscreens; the more common capacitive touchscreens will require a special stylus. That said, there are [clearly a wide variety of them on the market](http://www.google.com/search?q=capacitive+stylus).

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous solutions out there to your problem.  A good one on that works on Android and Windows Mobile is http://www.gocanvas.com 
If you are trying to use iPhone you can try http://www.iformbuilder.com/

Keep in mind, one of the downsides with using a web based solution, is that it won't work when you are offline (out of coverage) - which is needed alot with signature capture.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

There is a signature capture library available for Android devices. You can read more at:
http://www.binarysolutions.biz/2010/12/signature-capture-for-android.html

Answer (score 0):

I am putting together (slowly) some views for use in Android. Here is the source for it on github.

[CustomViews](https://github.com/CoatedMoose/CustomViews)

Comment: Hi, thanks for sharing the code, any idea why your SignatureView saves a blank bitmap (blank)?

Comment: It has been a while since I took a look at it. It iirc, it saves a white signature on a background with alpha=0. So it may not be blank. You can change the color of the signature, or the background. If you are still having problems, please create an issue on the GitHub repo.

Answer (score -1):

This app is published on android market and it is free. Looks like a perfect solution to me if you would like to capture signature on an android device.
https://market.android.com/details?id=AB.AN&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwyLDEsIkFCLkFOIl0

Comment: The above link is not available, Please try to update the same