# Android signature capture

Tags: android, signature

I want to capture the signature of user in my app is this possible, please provide your suggestions how would I proceed on this

Regard's 
Saurabh

Comment: There is an android library for signature capturing and you could integrate it in your own program. Check out http://bit.ly/scfahp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have never seen this done before, but i cannot imagine it being impossible. If given this problem I would do it by providing some area for the user to "sign" on and capturing [MotionEvents](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html) . Depending on how much memory you want to take up vs. how accurate you want the signature to be you will have to apply some sort of filtering to the collection of events you obtain.

With all this said, I'm curious as to why you want to capture the signature of your user? I am having a hard time imagining a situation where that would be useful.

Comment: Actually the project I am working on has requirement of capturing signature of user also I have looked in to gesture overaly sample how about going that way

Answer (score 0):

Namirial provides solutions for that scenario. You can integrate the Namirial signature solution, which allows your users to sign a PDF document, into your Android application as an SDK.

Namirial provides client/server based products (SIGNificant), workflow based products (visit https://saas.esignanywhere.net to get your free trial) and standalone apps (xyzmo) for different platforms (Android, iOS, Windows).