# Inside Scrollview SignatureView is not working

Tags: android, android-layout, signature

1. I put `Signatureview` inside Android `Scrollview`.
2. But while writing something on `SignatureView`, scrolling up and down I'm not able to write my sign.

How to Disable the `Scrollview` when `SignatureView` is touched

[Link to referred signature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6834354/how-to-capture-human-signature)

Sign.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        >

<ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:isScrollContainer="false"
            android:paddingBottom="30dp"
            android:paddingLeft="2dp"
            android:paddingRight="2dp"
            android:scrollbars="none">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">


        <com.kyanogen.signatureview.SignatureView
            xmlns:sign="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/signature_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:minHeight="250dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            sign:penSize="5dp"
            sign:backgroundColor="#ffffff"
            sign:penColor="#000000"
            sign:enableSignature="true"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="2">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/clearSignButton"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="clear"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/saveSignButton"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="save"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
 </LinearLayout>
</Scrolview>
```

Main.java

```
package com.example.parsaniahardik.signaturedemo;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.media.MediaScannerConnection;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import com.kyanogen.signatureview.SignatureView;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Bitmap bitmap;
    Button clear,save;
    SignatureView signatureView;
    String path;
    private static final String IMAGE_DIRECTORY = "/signdemo";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        signatureView =  (SignatureView) findViewById(R.id.signature_view);
        clear = (Button) findViewById(R.id.clear);
        save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.save);

        clear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                signatureView.clearCanvas();
            }
        });

        save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                bitmap = signatureView.getSignatureBitmap();
                path = saveImage(bitmap);
            }
        });


    }
    public String saveImage(Bitmap myBitmap) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        myBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bytes);
        File wallpaperDirectory = new File(
                Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + IMAGE_DIRECTORY /*iDyme folder*/);
        // have the object build the directory structure, if needed.
        if (!wallpaperDirectory.exists()) {
            wallpaperDirectory.mkdirs();
            Log.d("hhhhh",wallpaperDirectory.toString());
        }

        try {
            File f = new File(wallpaperDirectory, Calendar.getInstance()
                    .getTimeInMillis() + ".jpg");
            f.createNewFile();
            FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(f);
            fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
            MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(MainActivity.this,
                    new String[]{f.getPath()},
                    new String[]{"image/jpeg"}, null);
            fo.close();
            Log.d("TAG", "File Saved::--->" + f.getAbsolutePath());

            return f.getAbsolutePath();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "";

    }
}
```

Comment: signatureview is inside Linearlayout not Scrollview ?

Comment: Where is scrollview ? i can't see scrollview at Sign.xml

Comment: @ViramP See my updated question

Comment: Sorry,but i checked with your code and all working well.

Answer (score 5):

when you want to sign you need to intercept the scroll event **when the signature is touched.** and when you are outside of the signature area turn back the normal status: **the scrollView intercept the scroll event**.
inside onCreate in your controller add the following :

```
signatureView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener(){
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            int action = motionEvent.getAction();
            switch (action){
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    // Disable the scroll view to intercept the touch event
                    scrollView1.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                    return false;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    // Allow scroll View to interceot the touch event
                    scrollView1.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                    return true;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    scrollView1.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                    return false;
                default:
                    return true;
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to intercept touch events in this SignatureView. The best approach is to subclass it and override onTouchEvent:

```
public class MySignatureView extends SignatureView {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        // intercept touch event here, so it's not passed to ScrollView
        super.onTouchEvent(event);
        return false;
    }
}
```

And then, of course change SignatureView to MySignatureView in your layout.

```
<com.your.package.name.MySignatureView
        xmlns:sign="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/signature_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:minHeight="250dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        sign:penSize="5dp"
        sign:backgroundColor="#ffffff"
        sign:penColor="#000000"
        sign:enableSignature="true"/>
```

Comment: where i have to keep that Class Mysignatureview?

Comment: Wherever you want. You can use anonymous class, inner class or completely separate class to do that.

Comment: Can you let me know ,in my code where i have to modify  what you suggested else add full code of Signature capture inside scrolview